# Creating a document-feature matrix from list of extracted phrases after using phrasemachine (R)

Tags: r, dplyr, nlp, plyr, nested-lists

I have a nested list with phrases after applying `phrasemachine()`. Now I would like to create a document-feature matrix having the documents (user) in the first column and all features as the remaining columns with each user's frequency of usage in the cells.

```
library(rJava)
library(phrasemachine)
library(quanteda)

#creating dummy data
id <- c(1:2)
text <- c("Election day is coming up and I am super excited. Election day. Wooho. I voted President Obama.", "School is boring. Partying is cool. Happy Birthday to me. When is Election Day?")
test <- data.frame(id, text)
test$text <- as.character(test$text)

corpus_test <- corpus(test[["text"]], docnames = test[["id"]])
tokens_test <- tokens(corpus_test)
phrases_test <- phrasemachine(tokens_test, minimum_ngram_length = 2, maximum_ngram_length = 3, return_phrase_vectors = TRUE, return_tag_sequences = TRUE)
phrases_test

# > phrases_test
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$phrases
# [1] "Election_day"    "Election_day"    "President_Obama"
# 
# [[1]]$tags
# [1] "NN" "NN" "NN"
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$phrases
# [1] "Happy_Birthday" "Election_Day"  
# 
# [[2]]$tags
# [1] "AN" "NN"
```

This is the output I am looking for (a document-feature matrix):

```
# user    Election_day    President_Obama   Happy_Birthday
# 1       2               1                 0
# 2       1               0                 1
```

I tried using `lapply` but since each user's phrases are of different dimensions, that wouldn't work.

Here is what I tried:

```
library(plyr)
phrases_user <- laply(phrases_test, function(x) laply(x, identity)) #Error: Results must have the same dimensions.

library(dplyr)
phrases_user <- lapply(phrases_test, `[`, "phrases")
```

After figuring out the issue in extracting the phrases per Id, I suppose I would have to do the following:

```
corpus_test_2 <- corpus(phrases_user[["phrases"]], docnames = phrases_user[["id"]])
dfm_test <- dfm(corpus_test_2)
```

Can anyone help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example using udpipe with phrasemachine

```
library(udpipe)
text <- c("Election day is coming up and I am super excited. Election day. Wooho. I voted President Obama.", "School is boring. Partying is cool. Happy Birthday to me. When is Election Day?")
x <- udpipe(text, "english")
x$tags <- as_phrasemachine(x$upos, type = "upos")

keyw <- keywords_phrases(x$tags, 
                         term = x$token, pattern = "(A|N)*N(P+D*(A|N)*N)*", 
                         is_regex = TRUE, detailed = FALSE)
head(keyw)
x$term <- txt_recode_ngram(x$token, 
                           compound = keyw$keyword, 
                           ngram = keyw$ngram)
dtm <- document_term_frequencies(x, document = "doc_id", term = c("term", "token"))
dtm <- document_term_matrix(dtm)
```

Note though you might also be interested in using the dependency parsing output. You can extract multi-word expressions based on the `dep_rel` field of the udpipe output - if it says fixed/flat/compound, that are multi-word-expressions. The definition of fixed/flat/compound is defined at http://universaldependencies.org/u/dep/index.html.